# Run and wait scope for Munit Testing

Tags: mule

I am testing a batch processing flow using munit. Used Synchronize Run and wait scope to trigger batch flow for testing. It works well when running locally in anypoint studio. But when trying to deploy it using jenkins it shows Timeout waiting for async operations eventhough my wait time in the scope is 15 mins.

Comment: Anyone found a solution to this issue?